# react monaco-editor findWithArgs

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

I'm using @monaco-editor/react

```
editor.trigger(undefined, 'editor.actions.findWithArgs', {
  searchString: 'abc',
  replaceString: '',
  isRegex: false,
  preserveCase: true,
  findInSelection: false,
  matchWholeWord: true,
  isCaseSensitive: false,
});

// or

editor.trigger(undefined, 'editor.actions.findWithArgs', 'abc')
```

The result:

[image]

But i want:

[image]

editor.api.d.ts
[image]

what should i do